# Make use of "Favorite Tags" data to the full extent

Tags: discussion, feature-request

SO provides a great deal of options for preferred tags which it calls as **"Favorite Tags"** and **"Ignored Tags"**.

This data according to me, ***isn't*** used to its maximum capacity in all pages except the home page.

The `(Featured|Newest|Votes|Frequent|Active|Unanswered)` page,, shows up questions regarding Perl, Scala, C++, etc.. Why on earth would I need them? I don't know even a bit about them, but still I'm left to gaze at those questions, while what I know well isn't easily available to me.

All I'm interested in, is [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript),[c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23),[jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery),[regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and few more tags.

Not only the current system makes it hard for us to find interesting and answerable questions, it is also *non-productive*.

Of course many will suggest "you can use search by tags, use `or` and `and` syntax to navigate", but its a bit overkill especially when SO servers have all the data of what our preferred tag is.

So let all pages use the "Favorite Tags" data already stored in the server to the maximum extent and show only those questions which we know, we can answer and turn ourselves more *productive*.

Answer (score 2):

> The (Featured|Newest|Votes|Frequent|Active|Unanswered) page,, shows up questions regarding Perl, Scala, C++, etc.. Why on earth would I need them? I don't know even a bit about them, but still I'm left to gaze at those questions, while what I know well isn't easily available to me.

The site doesn't show *me* questions that I don't care about, since I have added these tags to my "ignored tags" list (and checked the option on the preferences page to hide the questions, rather than just gray them out). I update this list regularly, whenever I see stuff I don't care about appearing with some frequency (or just too low of a signal-to-noise ratio).

But there is a reason why we have two options: favorite and ignored. Just because a handful of tags are my favorites doesn't mean that I don't care at all about other tags. For example, maybe my favorite language is [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), and I want to make sure that I don't miss these questions. But I also know and am willing to help people asking about [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), and maybe even [vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6). I don't want these questions emphasized as favorites, but I don't want them to be ignored, either.

If you really don't care about a particular tag and don't want to see questions with that tag, you should add them to you ignored tags list.

> All I'm interested in, is [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript),[c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23),[jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery),[regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and few more tags.

Now, granted, I think I see where you're coming from here. Given the immense breadth of topics covered under "programming", most of our users only have a handful of tags in which they are knowledgeable.

I said that the site effectively filters out questions I'm unlikely to care about, since I use the "ignored tags" list. But to be fair, I have approximately 8.7 zillion tags on that list.

[image]

It would arguably be easier to maintain if we had a feature to ignore all *but* the following tags. However, it would be a mistake to conflate "favorite" tags with "ignored" tags, which is what you seem to be suggesting in the question. They are not the same.